# String-Output: Class@#

Tags: java, string, output, memory-address

Lets say I have three classes:

Class A:

```
public class A {
  private String s;

  public A() {
    s = "blah";
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B{
  private A a[];

  public B(){
    a = new A[100];
    for (int i=0; i<100;i++) {
      a[i] = new A();
    }
  }

  public void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      a.print();  //SHOULD BE a[i].print();
    }
  }
}
```

Class Main:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    b.print();
  }
}
```

Why do I get an outputpattern like `B@#`, where `#` is a number. I think it has something to do with indirect adressing but im not quite sure. Why doesn't it print out 100 `s`?

Comment: try to show your output

Comment: the output in my program is B@1172e08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the array rather than the object in the array. As a result, it is printing the address of the object (the number) and the object it is a member of.

I suspect you wanted to call each of the prints, you should, in B.print(). You are also missing an increment for i, meaning it will loop indefinitely.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    a[i].print();
}
```